# How change a string looks like array to a real aray

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string, it looks like a array but not a real array. So my question is how to make it to a real array.

```
let string = "["abc", "cde"]";
// how to make string become an array
```

change string to an array

Comment: `const array = JSON.parse(string);` However, the code in your question uses invalid syntax for the string. Double quotes within a double-quoted string must be [escaped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences). See example here: https://tsplay.dev/wQ347m

Comment: even I've changed  let string = "[`abc`, `cde`]";
and then    return JSON.parse(string);  
I got string is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
let data = "['abc', 'pqr', 'xxx']";
data = data.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(data)
const convertedArray = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(convertedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure your string is invalid format

```
"["abc", "cde"]" // invalid
"[abc, cde]" // invalid
"[11, 22]" // valid,if you do not want to use quote to wrap it,then the elements need to be number
"['abc', 'cde']" // valid
```

```js
let string = `["abc", "cde"]`
const array = JSON.parse(string)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I try it I got "abccde" instead an array
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-newton-b55vgn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @19020051PhạmTrungNghĩa I do not know what's your problem

Comment: sorry, you can check that link again

Comment: @19020051PhạmTrungNghĩa the reason is  that you have output the entire array,not output them one by one

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** Your input string is not a valid JSON string.

**Solution :** Double quotes besides the array items should be escaped to parse it properly. Your final string should be.

```
let string = "[\"abc\", \"cde\"]";
```

Now you can parse it using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let string = "['abc', 'cde']";
string = string.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(string); // "[\&quot;abc\&quot;, \&quot;cde\&quot;]"
console.log(JSON.parse(string)); // ["abc", "cde"]
```